# how to use onmouseover in this code?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to use onmouseover in this javascript code. So, whenever I move the mouse over the square, the function **changeColor** executes and picks one color each time, from the two given colors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Canvas Art Gallary</h1>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="300" style="border:10px solid #c3c3c3">
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeColor(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#04B45F";
}
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(150,100,100,100);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your question 'how to create a mouseover event handler in javascript' ? ( *not seeing any mouseover event in the code* ) cheers

Comment: I don't believe there is any native support for mouse events on canvas elements. However I have used the Kinetic JS library which does have event handling implemented: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/

Comment: Yes, rob, how would I create it?? that's what i'm aking for?? I know I have to use onmouseover somewhere in the code and place the function changeColor there, but where would I and how???

Comment: You should take a reference to the position of rectagle in the canvas, then on mouseover(htmlcanvaselement obviously already support the mouseover event), check if your mouse pointer is on bound of rectangle, the other way is use a canvas framework like Fabricjs or Paperjs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Listen for mouse events and toggle the color on our own custom `mouseenter`**

Note: the rect does not have `mouseenter` so we must custom build one.

- Listen for mousemove events
- On rect mouseenter: set a wasInside flag to true and changeColor() which toggles the rect color
- On rect mouseleave: clear a wasInside flag to indicate the mouse has left the rect.

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9GcbH/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color:ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;background-color:black;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
    var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

    var toggle=0;
    var x=150;
    var y=100;
    var w=100;
    var h=100;
    var wasInside=false;

    // draw the rect to start
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h); 

    function changeColor(){
      if(toggle==0){
          ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
          toggle=1; 
      }else{
          ctx.fillStyle = "#04B45F"; 
          toggle=0;
      }
      ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h); 
    } 


    function handleMouseMove(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        var my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

        var isInsideNow=(mx>x && mx<x+w && my>y && my<=y+h);

        if(isInsideNow && !wasInside){
            changeColor();
            wasInside=true;
        }else if(!isInsideNow && wasInside){
            wasInside=false;
        }

    }

    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Rect color toggles white-green<br>each time mouse moves over it.</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**[ Addition: explain steps of toggling ]**

Each time the mouse enters the rect changeColor is called.

changeColor both changes the color and also changes toggle.

Here's a step-by-step:

```
1. toggle==0 at the beginning of the ap
2. mouse enters rect and changeColor is called.
3. changeColor changes color to #ffffff because toggle==0.
4. changeColor changes toggle=1
5. mouse exits rect
6. mouse enters rect again and changeColor is called again.
7. changeColor changes color to #04b45f because toggle==1.
8. changeColor changes toggle=0;
```

Comment: how come am I still able to see the green(#04B45f) color even when the system never executes the else statement because toggle = 0 and you have the toggle = 1 after the code but that doesn't mean that it'll go through the else code, does it?? I think it wont coz the check has already taken place above and yet the code still works, how??

Comment: In my fiddle I initially drew the rectangle in green. In the code example above I set initially drew the rectangle in red (to indicate it had never been mouseenter'ed.

Comment: I still dont understand how is it changing to green when the "else" cmd never goes through!!

Comment: I added a step-by-step explanation of how the toggling works :-)

Comment: Ahh, thanks got ya, I'm from Java so I was thinking no while loop, so the program will never go through the if else code again. Btw how do you select the best answer???

Answer (score 0):

`mouseover` will only know when you're over the canvas, so you need to detect you're above the  square (I'm using the variables already defined by you):

```
var sqx1 = c.offsetLeft +  150; //left top corner of the square respect to the window
var sqy1 = c.offsetTop + 100;
var sqx2 = sqx1 + 100;  //right bottom corner of the square respect to the window
var sqy2 = sqy1 + 100;

var lastOverSquare = false;
c.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
     var overSquare = 
          (sqx1 <= e.pageX && sqx2 >= e.pageX) &&
          (sqy1 <= e.pageY && sqy2 >= e.pageY);

     if (overSquare && !lastOverSquare) changeColour(); //change only when it enters the square, not every move when we're already over it.
     lastOverSquare = overSquare;
}, false);

var colours = ['#FFFFFF', '#04B45F'];
var currentColour = 0;
ctx.fillStyle = colours[currentColour];
function changeColour() {
    currentColour = (currentColour + 1) % colours.length;
    ctx.fillStyle = colours[currentColour];
}
```